# Check if array is in another array and they are identical

Tags: php

I have a `$_SESSION['basket']` containing multiple arrays. I want to check if this `$_SESSION['basket']` variable contains a specific array and that they have the same values.

For example, I want to check that `$my_array` which is an array is the same as `$_SESSION['basket'][i]`.

`$_SESSION['basket']` would contain multiple arrays as follow :

```
$_SESSION['basket'] = array(
  [0] => array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2"
  );
  [1] => array(
    "key3" => "value3",
    "key4" => "value4"
  );
  [2] => array(
    "key5" => "value5",
    "key6" => "value6"
  );
);
```

And `$my_array` would contain :

```
array(
  "key3" => "value3",
  "key4" => "value4"
);
```

So I want to make sure that the `$my_array` variable is contained inside the `$_SESSION['basket']` variable and it's values are exactly the same obviously. Is there a way to do that without having to use a loop? If not, how to do it with a loop nonetheless?

Comment: Can you show us what do they actually contain in them, as an example reference?

Comment: @vivek_23 I wrote some more detail as requested.

Comment: I have added my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you will have to use a loop. Even if you use any PHP API, it loops under the hood anyway.

```
<?php 

function checkIfExists($haystack,$needle){
  foreach($haystack as $each_needle){
      if(isEqual($each_needle,$needle)) return true;
  }

  return false;
}

function isEqual($test,$original){
  foreach($original as $each_key => $each_value){
    if(!isset($test[$each_key]) || $test[$each_key] !== $each_value) return false;
  }

  return count($test) === count($original);
}


$_SESSION['basket'] = array(
  array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2"
  ),
  array(
    "key3" => "value3",
    "key4" => "value4"
  ),
  array(
    "key5" => "value5",
    "key6" => "value6"
  )
);

$my_array = array(
  "key3" => "value3",
  "key4" => "value4"
);

var_dump(checkIfExists($_SESSION['basket'],$my_array));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: Neat. Thanks! :)

Comment: Why do you have to use a loop?

Comment: @Progrock Just another way of doing it.

Comment: Above you state that you have to use a loop, but you don't.

Comment: Then what is "foreach" ?

Comment: My bad English, what I meant is that a simple in_array call would do.  'Will have to' is misleading is it not?

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
<?php

$basket =
array(
  array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2"
  ),
  array(
    "key3" => "value3",
    "key4" => "value4"
  ),
  array(
    "key5" => "value5",
    "key6" => "value6"
  )
);

$needle  = array(
  "key3" => "value3",
  "key4" => "value4"
);

var_dump(in_array($needle, $basket));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: Will that work with multiple dimensions? If $needle is a 2+ dimensional array, and $basket's array are also 2+ dimensional?

Comment: @Emiffiba, Note the haystack above is two dimensional, and the needle is one dimensional. You could search a three dimensional array for a two dimensional needle match. e.g. https://3v4l.org/o7J10